# How to not show null in errorText placeholder?

Tags: flutter

On the side of the block, I do a condition check and, if an error occurs, I send this error to the page.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (error) {
    sink.addError('Error description');
}
```

Thus, if there is no error, then error == null. And thus, if there is no error, then `null` is displayed on the page in the place where the error is shown.
As far as I know null was not displayed before in the errorText field, but if you do not write `snapshot.error.toString()` it shows an error in ide:

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String?'.

How to get around this so as not to write such a long check for the errorText field?

```
TextField(
    ...
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      ...
      errorText: snapshot.error.toString() == 'null'
          ? ''
          : snapshot.error.toString(),
    ),
),
```

Comment: var text = snapshot.error ?? "your text" ,
this expression mean if  snapshot.error have value text = snapshot.error else snapshot.error is null then text="your text";